# "Onus" rendu par "fardeau"

Tags: traduction, anglais

La phrase ci-après :

> The onus of avoiding infinite loops lies with the user.

peut-elle se traduire par :

> Le fardeau d'éviter les boucles infinies incombe à l'utilisateur.

ou fardeau est-il trop « pompeux » ?

Comment: *Fardeau* semble-t-il pompeux ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Désolé mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre ton commentaire.

Comment: "Fardeau" is closer to "burden" than "onus". A "fardeau" is something that is specifically *hard* to bear, and not just something that you have to bear.

Comment: @dimitris Suggesting a more natural wording for the last line of the question. When you choose not to invert with a subject pronoun it's okay : "Tu veux du riz ?" but when your subject is not pronominal the subject pronoun should actually be inserted too: "Fardeau semble-t-**il** pompeux ?"

Comment: @LukeSawczak : Merci ! Peut-on utiliser également "Fardeau **sonne**-t-il pompeux ?"

Comment: @dimitris Pour moi « sonner [adj.] » est un anglicisme à éviter, mais peut-être qu'un francophone pourra nous le vérifier !

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Sonner* peut être utilisé au sens figuré en français, mais seulement dans des expressions qui pourraient aussi s'appliquer au sens propre, c'est à dire à une cloche : *sonner bien*, *sonner mal*, *sonner juste*, *sonner faux*, *sonne mieux*, etc. *Sonner pompeux* n'est donc en effet pas idiomatique.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Je constate aussi que chacune de ces expressions-là comprend un adverbe, ce qui suggère que « sonner [adj.] » est exclu.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, il y a aussi *sonner creux, sonner clair* où *creux* et *clair* sont utilisés comme adverbes.

Comment: @LukeSawczak J'ai vu hier sur le mur côté Seine du Louvre une immense affiche publicitaire qui affirme son origine française tout en utilisant l'anglicisme *sonner anglais*... : https://www.presse-citron.net/deezer-ca-sonne-anglais-mais-cest-francais/

Comment: You really need to provide the links to these sentences as they are in books and require attribution.

Comment: Et puis si Luke veut tout savoir, on peut dire: L'utilisateur qui doit s'amuser en faisant des corvées pareilles devient complètement sonné, en fin de compte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, fardeau est exagéré ici.

*Onus* a ici le sens **c** du Merriam Webster (*blame*) et à la définition ***3*** de *blame*, on trouve :

> *responsibility for something believed to deserve censure
> they must share the blame*

Une traduction appropriée peut donc être :

> La responsabilité d'éviter les boucles infinies incombe à l'utilisateur.

C'est celle qui est donnée aujourd'hui par DeepL.

Voici d'autres références ou *responsabilité* est utilisé ([Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/the+onus)):

> *Such requirements illogically placed the **onus** of nuclear disarmament on those States.*
>
> De telles exigences font injustement reposer la **responsabilité** du désarmement nucléaire sur ces États.

> *As always, the **onus** for compliance rests with member organizations themselves.*
>
> Comme toujours, la **responsabilité** de la conformité relève des organisations membres elles-mêmes.

Un autre exemple où *onus* ne peut pas être traduit par "fardeau" ou "corvée" :

> Richard Rosen writes that the Goldstone Commission
> effectively “placed the **onus** of avoiding civilian casualties entirely on Israel.”
> Source: *The Roles and Functions of Atrocity-Related United Nations Commissions of Inquiry in the International Legal Order*, Catherine Harwood, 2020

Dans cette phrase, traduire *onus* par « corvée » ou « fardeau » ne manquerait pas de déclencher un incident diplomatique.

Comment: responsabilité ici est une "sur traduction".

Comment: @Lambie et ton commentaire, un "sous-commentaire".

Comment: Voilà le problème. Il ne s'agit pas de "responsabilité" ici. Il s'agit d'un truc enmerdant qu'on est obligé de faire, qui pèse sur l'utilisateur.  On ne peut pas traduire pas des synonymes "apparents". "Le contexte est plus fort que le concept".

Comment: @Lambie Donc d'après toi, il faut traduire cette phrase par: *Le truc emmerdant que l'utilisateur est obligé de faire, c'est d'éviter les boucles infinies* ?

Answer (score 14):

La traduction mot à mot est souvent à éviter; je dirais:

> Il incombe à l'utilisateur d'éviter les boucles infinies.

Comment: Yes, that's a better overall way to say it. *Onus* is lost in translation though...

Comment: "This is professional grade." Eviter les boucles infinies est une charge qui incombe à l'utilisateur. Onus=une charge.

Comment: @jlliagre — « ***La corvée*** d'éviter les boucles infinies incombe à l'utilisateur. » —  «  Il  incombe à l'utilisateur d'éviter ***la faute*** des boucles infinies.— (Merci DeepL :-)

Comment: @Personne Excellent, c'est une corvée. Bravo.

Comment: @Lambie Non, *corvée* est beaucoup trop fort dans ce contexte, comme l'était *fardeau*.

Comment: @jlliagre Il vaut mieux une tâche laborieuse qui est bien une corvée que le mot responsabilité.

Comment: @jlliagre — Pas vraiment d'accord « Être de corvée de chiotte » n'est pas un fardeau comme celui d'avoir un parent à problème. L'une est passagère et peu agréable, l'autre amène souffrance et épuisement moral.

Comment: @Personne Je comprends mais je trouve *corvée* quand même beaucoup trop fort dans le contexte de la question. S'assurer qu'il n'y aura pas de boucles infinies, on peut considérer que c'est une tâche fastidieuse, mais je trouve que *corvée* serait aussi incongru que si on l'utilisait dans le premier exemple que j'ai ajouté à ma question, : *De telles exigences font injustement reposer la **corvée** du désarmement nucléaire sur ces États.*

Comment: @Personne Je viens de mettre à jour ma réponse pour expliquer pourquoi je ne peux pas non plus traduire *onus* par "corvée" dans la phrase de la question.

Comment: @jlliagre … dans ce contexte diplomatique, *fardeau* conviendrait tout à fait, dire que c'est « à la *charge* » est une litote pour ceux qui hérite des déchets nucléaires. En revanche tu peux compléter ta réponse par « Éviter les boucles infinies ***est à la charge*** de l'utilisateur. »

Comment: @Personne Tu dirais vraiment qu'éviter les morts de civils est un *fardeau* ??

Comment: @jlliagre … oui dans ses conséquences Les armes nucléaires n'ont jamais servi depuis la dernière guerre mondiale, elles ont évité de nombreux morts pour les pays qui possèdent la bombe atomique. Assumer le désarmement nucléaire n'est pas une séance de Bisounours (équilibre des forces et déchets, contrôle), « *De telles exigences font injustement* … » la notion d'injustice convient parfaitement au *fardeau*, c'est sa nature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130764/discussion-between-personne-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 4):

Au lieu de *fardeau* effectivement un peu exagéré, je préférerais la ***tâche*** quand le travail en question nécessite effectivement un certain effort.

Mais lorsqu'il s'agit d'une évidence dans le travail qui demande en fait plus de ***soin*** que d'effort, c'est alors plus souvent ce mot que l'on rencontre.

*On laisse à l'utilisateur le soin d'éviter les boucles infinies, le soin d'éteindre la lumière, le soin de se déconnecter...*

Comment: onus signale un poid ou une charge.....pas un soin.

Comment: @Lambie … *soin* n'est pas ici en rapport avec la santé, mais avec *le travail soigné*, la tâche terminée dans les règles le l'art.

Comment: @Personne Je ne dis pas que soin ici a un rapport avec la santé. Le soin que l'on apporte à quelque chose. C'est un peu fatiguant de lire des commentaires sur presque tout que je dis comme si je ne savais pas les mots basiques de la langue....

Comment: @lambie … dans le cas des boucles, la charge (notion juridique), le poids (des contraintes et règlements) ne sont pas de mise. les notions apportées ici par  *onus* peuvent être entendu comme une exagération verbale pour attirer l'attention à porter au *travail soigné* … ou alors c'est une menace juridique subliminale : « nous ne sommes pas responsables de vos erreurs, de vos tests et autres recettes, ce qui est possible si cette phrase est extraite des conditions de maintenance.

Comment: @Personne Dire que *onus* implique un travail soigné, c'est sauter du coq à l'âne...il n'y a aucune notion juridique dans le texte.

Comment: @Lambie … cette notion n'est pas dans le texte, mais induite dans votre commentaire sur *onus*, et ensuite développée dans ma réponse sur ce point seulement, comprenne qui pourra. Traduire n'est pas programmable à partir d'un dictionnaire, mais un choix d'expressions correspondant au contexte qui impose ses solutions, et à la tournure d'esprit et ses modes d'expression qui ne sont pas du tout les mêmes des deux côtés de la Manche :-) .

Comment: @Personne Croyez-moi, je sais ce que c'est traduire. Allez, bonne journée. :)

Comment: @Lambie *C'est un peu fatiguant de lire des commentaires sur presque tout que je dis comme si je ne savais pas les mots basiques de la langue* C'est peut-être parce que tu fais des commentaires un peu partout qui montrent parfois que tu ne maitrises pas toutes les subtilités de la langue.

Comment: @jlliagre Selon certains, c'est mon anglais qui n'est pas "suffisant"....

Comment: @Lambie Il faut rester humble, on peut bien sûr se tromper aussi sur sa langue maternelle, et de toute façon, on n'en connait jamais non plus toutes les subtilités, c'est une question de degré.